# VueRouter, VueJS, and Laravel route guard

Tags: vuejs2, vue-router

I wanted to hide a particular page of my application behind a layer of security (a simple passcode form that will send a request to the server for validation).

Based off the documentation of VueRouter, I figured a `beforeEnter` would be appropriate. However, I am not entirely sure how one would require a user to access a particular component, and then successfully enter a passcode before being allowed to proceed to this current route.

Does anyone have an example of this? I am having trouble finding anything similar.

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';

Vue.use(VueRouter);

const routes = [
  { path: '/test/:testURL', component: require('./components/test.vue'), 
    beforeEnter: (to, from, next) => {
           // somehow load another component that has a form
           // the form will send a request to Laravel which will apply some middleware
           // if the middleware successfully resolves, this current route should go forward. 
    }
  },
];

const router = new VueRouter({
  routes,
  mode: 'history',
});

const app = new Vue({
  router
}).$mount('#app');
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you want to perform authentication only for selected components, you can go with using **beforeEnter** route guard. Use the following code.

```
const routes = [
  { path: '/test/:testURL', component: require('./components/test.vue'), 
    beforeEnter:requireLogin
  },
];

function requireLogin(to, from, next) {
    if (authenticated) {
        next(true);
    } else {
        next({
            path: '/login',
            query: {
                redirect: to.fullPath
            }
        })
    }
}
```

Further, you can create a login screen and action in **login** component to redirect to given redirect **parameter** after setting **authenticated** variable to true. I recommend you to maintain **authenticated** variable in the veux store

Comment: This is great -- thanks a ton! I am not sure I need VueX in the project itself (I generally don't have any shared data at the moment). How would you maintain this authenticated variable otherwise? I was thinking something along the lines of a cookie rather than a variable, so I am curious what this approach would look like

Comment: Nice. Next best approach is catching this value in browser local storage. It actually has benefits.

Comment: I will look into the local storage bit! So I just realized this -- I am new to authentication and how this interacts with frontend (primarily worked with blade and the like prior). Is it wise to base the flow of the authentication based on the value of `authenticated`? Isn't this simply a variable stored in the frontend, that anyone could modify?

Comment: if you do only the front end verification yes you are right and even saving in javascript itself is not secure enough.